Brakes lurching
When braking from higher speeds my Ford Escape rumbles and vibrates excessively, at slower speeds it's a bit lurchy but fine if I'm very very gentle with the pedal. Thanks for anything you could help with.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

If you are only having vibration when braking it's probably due to warped brake rotors. Your brakes work by clamping pads onto a metal rotor (also called a disc), if that disc develops slight bends then the pads are alternately gripping and not gripping the surface, creating that vibration.
Your brake rotors need maintenance, they may be able to resurface them, or they may need to replace them. They should replace the pads as well.
Warping can happen from normal wear and tear, or it could be caused by a rotor overheating if a brake caliper is not releasing, your mechanic (or you if you do your own work) should check for that.
